# Dynamic forms singleton?

Tags: angular, forms, dynamic, angular7

I'm trying to understand the dynamic forms section in angular, and I'm not sure I understand it correctly.

For instance: I build a formgroup with form control, and send it to another component through input.

dynamic-form-component.html:

```
<div>
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form">
        <div *ngFor="let question of questions" class="form-row">
            <app-question [question]="question" [form]="form"></app-question>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <div *ngIf="payLoad" class="form-row">
        <strong>Saved the following values</strong><br>{{payLoad}}
    </div>
</div>
```

dynamic-form.component.ts:

```
   onSubmit() {
    this.payLoad = JSON.stringify(this.form.value);
  }
```

In the app-question component, this form will be changed I mean the fields will be fill with data options the user choose.

And when he done the user will be pressed on 'save' how the data is up to date? I mean I don't need to send the values back to the parent component? (send new form data from app-question > dynamic-form) is the form is singleton like service? So every change inside a components children, make the change in the parent form as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roberto, when you use @Input, and the input is an object, you needn't use output because you pass a "reference" of the object.

A silly example

Parent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <child [object]="object"></child>
  {{object|json}}` //<--after 1 seconds you can see { "property1": 1, "property2": 3 }
})
export class AppComponent {
  object={property1:1,property2:2}
}
```

Child

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `child`
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit  {
  @Input() name: any;
  ngOnInit()
  {
     setTimeout(()=>{
        this.name.property2=3
     },1000)
  }
}
```

With app-question pass as @Input "form" and "question". This is because the change on the app change the form: it's the same control! (not because form was some like a "singelton")